# How to Close the selenium webdriver if the url is not opening

Tags: java, selenium

There are many answers(`driver.close()`) there for this questions but none of them are helped me.
I try to open a website using selenium web driver for every minute.If the website was not opened within a minute code need to close the driver, but it is not closing.Because,the web page title is displaying as connecting.Please help me to work on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a direct way to accomplish this unless you kill the browser and quit the driver instance. The easiest way probably is to add some hardcoded delay and killed the session with JavaScript

```
driver.get("something");
Thread.sleep(1000);
//Alternative to javaScript is to use Actions Class and send ESC key to stop execution
//Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
//actions.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.stop;");
driver.quit();
```

**Edit**

If you want to add another way to bypass the killing of the session if in case the website loads properly try this

```
driver.get("");

 try {

     (new WebDriverWait(driver, 1)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.id("something we know should exist if page load");

 } catch (Exception ex) {

     //Alternative to javaScript is to use Actions Class and send ESC key to stop execution
     //Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
     //actions.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
     ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.stop;");
      driver.quit();
 }
```

Comment: One more issue, please post your mail id i will send my code to you.

Comment: i need to kill that driver, if it is not opened within a minute even if the webdriver is saying as "connecting".